# predeclared any requires go1.18 or later (-lang was set to go1.16; check go.mod)

Tags: go

Imported a module that has generics and now my code is throwing an error to check if go.mod is running 1.18 or later. Both my code and the module that was imported has go.mod file that says 1.20. If both modules have version 1.20 in go.mod why does it throw this error?

```
 type parameter requires go1.18 or later (-lang was set to go1.16; check go.mod)
```

Both go.mod files have version 1.20

```
go 1.20
```

Comment: A transitive dependency with `go1.16` maybe? Something getting an old version from the proxy rather than where you expect? There's got to be something in the code specifying `go1.16` somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

After an hour I ran another update of the modules and this time I noticed another module appears to have gotten upgraded.

```
go: upgraded github.com/mattn/go-isatty v0.0.17 => v0.0.18
```

Not sure how this got upgraded but it did. Maybe it takes time to get the updates from other packages. Or go mod has some method of knowing what to upgrade.

I'm no longer getting the error about go.mod version 1.18 or later.

```
jonathan.kittell@Jonathan-Kittell's-MacBook-Pro demo % go get -u all
go: downloading github.com/mattn/go-isatty v0.0.18
go: downloading github.com/jkittell/datastructures v0.0.0-20230420174618-e379a55b9a3c
go: upgraded github.com/jkittell/datastructures v0.0.0-20230420173253-66732def1378 => v0.0.0-20230420174618-e379a55b9a3c
go: upgraded github.com/mattn/go-isatty v0.0.17 => v0.0.18
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently encountered nearly the same error when building with `go1.21`:

```
vendor/github.com/gin-gonic/gin/context.go:1085:11: predeclared any requires go1.18 or later (-lang was set to go1.16; check go.mod)
```

I checked the `vendor/github.com/gin-gonic/gin/go.mod` only to find it declares using `go 1.18` already.

So where is the heck `go1.16` comes from?

After struggling hours I found my `vendor/modules.txt` have the following content:

```
380  github.com/gin-contrib/sse
381  ## explicit; go 1.18
382  github.com/gin-gonic/gin
...
1282  ## explicit
1283  github.com/gin-contrib/sse
1284  # github.com/gin-gonic/gin v1.8.1
1285  ## explicit
1286  github.com/gin-gonic/gin
1287  # github.com/go-playground/locales v0.14.0
1288  ## explicit
...
```

To clarify that, `vendor/modules.txt` consists of three types of content:

1. package name, without '#' prefix, e.g. `github.com/gin-contrib/sse`,
2. module and version, starting with '#', e.g. `# github.com/gin-gonic/gin v1.8.1`
3. an explicit mark, e.g. `## explicit` or `## explicit; go1.18`(with go version)

In my `vendor/modules.txt`, `# github.com/gin-gonic/gin v1.8.1` appears once, but following it is not a `## explicit` with go version, so `go 1.16` is assumed, that's where the weired message comes from.

To fix this, just add a line after  `# github.com/gin-gonic/gin v1.8.1`:

```
## explicit; go1.18
```

Or just go `go mod vendor` if possible.